# Geometric optic, displacement formula f=(L^2-d^2)/4L

Tags: solution-verification, mathematical-physics

Stupid question I am stuck at the displacement formula in geometric optic I am following the steps at [schoolphysics](https://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Optics/Refraction/text/Lenses_focal_length_measurement/index.html). The steps are the same more or less. But I cant for my mind see the steps wich ends up at

u = [d – a]/2 and v = [d + a]/2

and everywhere I look they just state it driving me nuts. Can someone please explain how they get to the expression?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a simple linear system. If  $d = u+v$ and $a = v-u$ then just look at the sum $d+a$ and $d-a$ to find $u$ and $v$.

Comment: that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.